# Copying a binary file outside of a jar

Tags: java, jar, exe, java.util.scanner, getresource

I have an exe packaged inside my jar file and I am trying to copy it to a temporary location so that i can run it using `Desktop.browse()`, to do this I set up a scanner with the input stream constructor using `class.getResourceAsStream`, and then with a `printwriter` wrote that all to a file. The problem that occurred says that the exe is invalid. I think this is due to some binary data being lost. If anyone can help please post a comment.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(ClassBuilder.class.getResourceAsStream("jd-gui.exe"));
    File copy = new File("C://users//Owner//Desktop//java//jd-gui.exe");
    copy.createNewFile();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(copy);

    while(sc.hasNextLine())
        writer.println(sc.nextLine());

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    sc.close();

    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(copy.toURI());
```

Comment: Please show the code. Make is short and sweet, only the pieces that matter: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Scanner is used to read text. PrintWriter is used to write text. An exe file is a binary file. Use streams.

Comment: You need to copy the .exe file to a new location ?

Comment: getResourceAsStream() returns an InputStream. Read bytes from this stream until you reach the end, and write them to a FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned use streams for binary data.  Commons io makes copying streams easy. Something like:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("jd-gui.exe");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jd-gui.exe");
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```