# How to use phantomjs.binary.path when PhantomJS is embedded inside a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs for headless browser testing. I call phantomjs from within my java file (MainTest.java). The code runs fine in my local machine. I bundle both the phantomjs.exe and the calling java file inside a jar file (tetsPhantom.jar).

- testPhantom.jar

  - phantomjs.exe
  - MainTest.java

On the server, it is failing when it tries to find the phantomjs executable path:

```
String webDir = LiExportEmails.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm(); // Returns http://myservername.com:8080/testPhatom.jar
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", webDir);
```

I have tried setting it to `http://myservername.com:8080/testPhatom.jar!phantomjs.exe` as well, but it still fails.

What should be the correct path of phantomjs located inside the same jar file as the caller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by using the approach from [JNLP Webstart Launch Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794711/jnlp-webstart-launch-issue) and [Copying a binary file outside of a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558626/copying-a-binary-file-outside-of-a-jar) , with one change:

```
File f = new File ("./phantomjs.exe");
if (!f.exists()) {
  InputStream in = Myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("phantomjs.exe");
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./phantomjs.exe");
  IOUtils.copy(in, out);
}
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path","./phantomjs.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think it is possible to execute an .exe from within a jar file even if you could resolve the path somehow. You should extract the phantomjs.exe.